# Will function store value if implemented in if statement?

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ code to perform Reverse Polish Notation math.  For this, I have a stack class that has a boolean method **pop(value)**

```
bool pop(int &value) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        value = stack[topIndex];
        return true;
    }
};
```

where the top value on the stack is stored in **value** and then is deleted off of the stack.  If the stack is empty, this pop method returns **false**, otherwise it returns **true**.

My question is, if I use the **pop** method like this:

```
int a, b;

if (!stack.pop(a) || !stack.pop(b)) {
    cout << "Error: stack is empty: << endl;
}
```

where both times it returns **true**, will the top value of the stack for each case be stored in **a** and **b** or do I need to implement the method outside of the **if** statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` is evaluated from left to right, so for

`if (!stack.pop(a) || !stack.pop(b)) {`

`a` is set first, then `b`.

Note also for your `pop` method that you never actually pop the stack -  you only return the top-most value.

Comment: Thank you.  And yes, my pop method is not removing the top element.  I will fix this.

Comment: @JordanTaylor IMO before writing any new data structure, it's better have 5 minute look on existing data structures. If you are with C++, I'd say you SHOULD look at std library data structures first. Then you can grab, what commonly used terms are. What is pop what is top likewise.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is fine. The logical or operator (`||`) short-circuits meaning the right side is only executed if the left side evaluates to false. In the case where the first pop succeeds, the left side is `false`, and therefore the right side will also be evaluated, and store the appropriate value if the stack is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

The value will be stored in both a and b.

**Note** a pop function traditionally removes the last element of a list and returns it to the caller. What you are doing is not a pop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pop function will be normally executed inside the if statement, so the value will be stored.